# Can not resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'

Tags: android, gradle, android-activity, appcompatactivity

After changing the applicationId, Android Studio can not resolve AppCompatActivity, DialogFragment, support V4 Fragment and similar items from support library.

[image: image error]

I have tried:

- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- Sync project with gradle files
- Detach gradle project sync and sync again
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Delete project and cloning again
- Remove all dependencies and adding one bye one
- Rename applicationId to previous name

This is my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.squivisur.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(path: ':ocr')
    implementation project(path: ':ucrop')
}
```

Is there anyway to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is most likely something to do with library implementations..
(a conflict of some sort I guess)
maybe something like:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation project(path: ':ocr')
implementation project(path: ':ucrop') }
```

the numbers can probably be updated..